# Matlab cftool producing wrong coefficients

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, polynomial-math

So i have this data

```
x
1.0423
2.8249
3.2016
2.0851
1.0299
4.7397
0.4104
0.5285
0.7102
0.8323
3.1048
2.8685
0.2604
4.6560
3.6433
3.6892
0.3170
4.3022
4.6720
4.9220
y
    2.0529
   -3.0669
   -2.3631
   -0.7300
    1.4354
    2.0260
    0.5980
    0.5296
    1.3405
    1.7361
   -1.5876
   -2.7872
    1.0788
    1.3677
   -0.1355
   -1.5755
    0.7811
   -0.8328
   -0.0592
    2.0927
```

And I tried to fit an 8th order polynomial to the data using cftool.

These are the results I get which are wrong

```
Linear model Poly8:
     f(x) = p1*x^8 + p2*x^7 + p3*x^6 + p4*x^5 + 
                    p5*x^4 + p6*x^3 + p7*x^2 + p8*x + p9
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =    -0.05446  (-0.126, 0.01711)
       p2 =       1.088  (-0.3839, 2.561)
       p3 =      -8.762  (-21.23, 3.706)
       p4 =        36.2  (-19.89, 92.3)
       p5 =      -80.85  (-225.3, 63.62)
       p6 =       94.32  (-119.9, 308.6)
       p7 =      -52.21  (-227.5, 123.1)
       p8 =       12.21  (-59.01, 83.42)
       p9 =    -0.05814  (-10.72, 10.61)

Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 4.083
  R-square: 0.9225
  Adjusted R-square: 0.8661
  RMSE: 0.6092
```

This is a cftool plot of the fit which looks fine
[image: Cftool plot of the fit which looks fine]

and this is what plotting the coefficients actually looks like.
[image: What plotting the coefficients actually looks like]

Code for plotting coefficients:

```
xx = 0:1/100:5;
yy = -0.05446*xx.^8 +1.088*xx.^7 -8.762*xx.^6 +36.2*xx.^5 -80.85*xx.^4 +94.32*xx.^3 -52.21*xx.^2 +12.21*xx -0.05814;
plot(xx,yy)
```

Does anyone know whats going on and how to get the correct coefficients of the plot that cftool produces?

Comment: Can we see your code for plotting the curve from the coefficients?

Comment: Your `x` and/or `y` data are wrong (they are identical).

Comment: @EgonGeerardyn Woops, thanks for that. I've edited the OP again to add in the actual x values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that by truncating the coefficients, you have changed the polynomial too much.

You can see the effect yourself, by examining following code (when you already have `x` and `y` in your workspace).

```
P = polyfit(x,y,8); % fitted polynomial
P2 = [-0.05446 1.088 -8.762 36.2 -80.85 94.32 -52.21 12.21 -0.0814]; % your coefficients

toString = @(x,pat)(sprintf(pat,x));
fix = @(x,pat)(str2double(toString(x,pat)));

P3 = arrayfun(@(x)(fix(x,'%3.4f')), P); % artificially truncate the coefficients

X = linspace(min(x),max(x),100);
Y  = polyval(P ,X);
Y2 = polyval(P2,X);
Y3 = polyval(P3,X);

figure;
[x,i] = sort(x);
y = y(i);
plot(x,y ,'or'); hold on;
plot(X,Y ,'-b'); 
plot(X,Y2,'--g');
plot(X,Y3,'-c');
hold off;
```

What I did, was fit the polynomial of eighth order to your data, I also truncated the coefficients artificially (I don't know the exact rounding strategy of `cftool`, it seems a bit more complicated than what I did).

In the figure below, you can see the outcome. The red dots are the data, the blue line is the exact polynomial as fitted with `polyfit` (and probably `cftool` as well). The dotted green line depicts your polynomial with truncated coefficients) and the cyan line shows my truncated polynomial. So you see that by truncating, you are changing the polynomial too much to be usable.

[image: Comparison of data and polynomials]

Comment: Ah, thankyou so much. These truncated coefficients was what cftool was giving me in the fitting GUI, so I'll probably use polyfit if there is no way of getting more precise coefficients from cftool.

Comment: @Michael: personally, I'd be very cautious using either of them. I don't know what you are trying to model, but it looks a lot like you are overfitting your data. My intuition says your signal is more like a sawtooth than an eighth order polynomial. And you can also see that no single coefficient is determined well from the standard deviations given by `cftool` (e.g. the polynomial y(x) = 0 lies within 95% uncertainty).

Answer (score 0):

I think you used x center and scale check box so you have normalized x and you have different answer when you write this yourself