# matlab sftool and truncated coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have tried using `sftool`. And using polynomial fitting (in the sftool) a satisfactory fitted plot is obtained in the surface fitting tool window. But when I use the coefficients (obtained from the sftool) in the polynomial equation and try to plot - a deviated surface plot from the original one is achieved.

I have found that the problem is due to the truncated coefficients problem as discussed in [Matlab cftool producing wrong coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756890/matlab-cftool-producing-wrong-coefficients)

But the solution in above mentioned link is for 2d curve fitting, not for the 3d surface fitting.

How can I solve the problem in a 3d case?

In addition, is there any other suitable way to fit my data (using parameters)?

my data is:

```
X =
   [ 1.321  1.3307 1.3404 1.3534 1.3681 1.3799 1.3898 1.3973 1.4048 1.4123 1.4202 1.4272 1.4372 1.4493 1.4619 1.4749 1.4892 1.5043 1.5165 1.53   1.5447 1.5569 1.5607 1.5653 1.5703 ;
     1.3375 1.3476 1.3602 1.3715 1.3824 1.3933 1.4041 1.4158 1.427  1.4387 1.4483 1.4563 1.465 1.4734  1.4809 1.4885 1.4968 1.504  1.5132 1.5178 1.5237 1.5283 1.5392 1.5527 1.5707 ;
     1.2998 1.3121 1.323  1.3335 1.3487 1.3639 1.3752 1.384  1.3929 1.4008 1.4084 1.4147 1.4214 1.4293 1.4397 1.4519 1.4644 1.4778 1.4882 1.4987 1.5079 1.5196 1.5305 1.5418 1.5704 ];

Y =
   [ 18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  18.301  ;
     18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 18.5185 ;
     18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 18.8261 ];

Z = 
   [ 1.0515 1.0773 1.103  1.1459 1.2489 1.4034 1.6953 1.9528 2.2189 2.485  2.7425 3.0086 3.2661 3.4464 3.5923 3.7124 3.8155 3.9099 3.9871 4.0644 4.1245 4.1588 4.1674 4.1931 4.1931 ;
     1.0086 1.0343 1.103  1.1803 1.3348 1.5494 1.7983 2.0815 2.3906 2.6652 2.8712 3.0086 3.1974 3.3691 3.4464 3.5579 3.6781 3.7382 3.824  3.8927 3.9356 3.9957 4.0901 4.1416 4.2275 ;
     1.3519 1.3348 1.3777 1.3777 1.3605 1.3691 1.412  1.4635 1.5236 1.5923 1.6781 1.7811 1.8755 2.03   2.2361 2.4506 2.691  2.9227 3.0944 3.2747 3.4034 3.5579 3.6867 3.824  4.03 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the OP in the question you referenced was to NOT use the coefficients produced by the `cftool`.  Instead the OP had to explicitly calculate them using `polyfit`. You can't use the polyfit tool to do your 3d problem, although a quick google search for "Matlab Polyfit 3d" has [this discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/168706) as the first hit, it should have everything you need to solve your problem.